# Azure Kubernetes Container Env Variables

Tags: azure, docker, azure-aks

so in Docker, I can do a Docker run -e  to pass in environment variables.

But how does one do that for Azure Kubernetes Pods?  They aren't username/password kinds of variables but more so URLs segments we would want to use during startup.

`http://webapi/august` where `august` is what we would want to pass in, then in September, we would want to pass in `september`.

This aren't the best examples, but it shows what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a clear example on kubernetes documentation for this - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/

Short example from there:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: DEMO_GREETING
          value: "Hello from the environment"
        - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
          value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

Take a note of `env`

later if you want to change the variable on the fly - you can use `kubectl set env -h` command

Comment: How would this work if I'm using the kind: Deployment option?

Comment: environment variables are defined on a container level, so it will work just the same. I updated my example